# What is causing g++ to produce the error: "ld.exe cannot find -lopencv_world310"?

Tags: windows, opencv, gcc, g++, mingw-w64

I am attempting to build an application using g++ that is composed of several source files and also uses OpenCV 3.1.0.

The CMD command is:

```
g++ -o home_surveillance -static -std=c++11 -m64 -IC:\Tools\OpenCV\opencv\build\include -LC:\Tools\OpenCV\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib -lopencv_world310 configuration_manager.cpp events.cpp image_processor.cpp main.cpp response_module.cpp scheduler.cpp
```

The error produced is:

```
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.2.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lopencv_world310
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have been trying various things and searching for answers for a couple days now. I should note that the application builds properly in Visual Studio 2015. I have tried compiling the source files using g++ with the -c option and they all seem to compile fine. It is just the linking phase that produces an error.

**Things I have tried:**

1. Just about every possible combination of the specified command. (Modifying order of the options, -lopencv_world310.a, -lopencv_world310.lib, -lopencv_world310, -l"full_path"+"opencv_world310", etc..)
2. Checked that all the paths and filenames are correct.
3. Reinstalled mingw to make sure I was using mingw-w64 since this is a 64-bit application.
4. Running CMD as admin thinking maybe CMD could not access the path specified with -L option.
5. Googling and reading every post I could find. (Most posts about "ld.exe cannot find "library_name" are a result of someone using "library_name".a or "library_name".lib as input to the -l option).
6. Reading mingw documentation on the use of GCC/g++ to ensure I wasn't missing anything obvious.
7. Praying to Bjarne Stroustrup.
8. Ritual sacrifice involving a Pentium 2.

Comment: Did you consider also building the OpenCV libraries with g++, if that's what you use to compile your application?

Comment: No, I didnt! I'll try that today and update the post with my results.

Comment: "Checked that all the paths and filenames are correct." How did that
convice you that there is a file in `C:\Tools\OpenCV\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib`
that the linker will recognize as matching the library option `-lopencv_world310`?

Comment: Because i've looked in that directory, and there are about 5 files. One of them is called opencv_world310(.lib).

Comment: I have OpenCV 3.1.0 installed in `C:\OpenCV`. Link options `-LC:\OpenCV\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib -lopencv_world310` work for me. The commandline you have posted cannot be exactly what you tried as there a syntax error in it - `IC:\Tools\OpenCV\opencv\build\include` is not a valid compiler option - that would stop the compiler before it gets started; so it may be untrue in other respects.

Comment: Oops, you're right. I've updated the post. I've tried many variations of the command that don't have that typo with the same result though. Did you do anything with GCC after you installed it (aside from adding it to PATH) or was that command working for you with the default configuration? I've tried reinstalling things and tried the build on 2 different windows machines now with the same results, I have to be doing something wrong.